# The target entry-point "@vcd/ui-components" has missing dependencies:

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-ivy

I'm getting the following error when I `npm start` the application at https://github.com/juanmendes/vmware-cloud-director-ui-components for the branch named `ryan-a11y-merge-to-master`. If I run the `master` branch, I get no errors.

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "@vcd/ui-components" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/core
 - @clr/angular
 - @angular/common
 - rxjs/internal-compatibility
 - @angular/platform-browser
 - @angular/core/testing
 - @angular/forms
 - @angular/router
 - rxjs
 - rxjs/operators
 - @clr/angular/data/datagrid/interfaces/filter.interface
```

I also see the following error messages before this final error:

```
Warning: Entry point '@vmw/ng-live-docs' contains deep imports into '/Users/jmendes/git/github/juan-core-ui/node_modules/prismjs/components/prism-scss', '/Users/jmendes/git/github/juan-core-ui/node_modules/prismjs/components/prism-typescript'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point '@vmw/plain-js-live-docs' contains deep imports into '/Users/jmendes/git/github/juan-core-ui/node_modules/lit-html/directives/unsafe-html'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point '@vcd/ui-components' contains deep imports into '/Users/jmendes/git/github/juan-core-ui/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/interfaces/filter.interface'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
```

If I ask colleagues to clone that repo and run it:

```
git clone https://github.com/juanmendes/vmware-cloud-director-ui-components.git
cd vmware-cloud-director-ui-components;
git checkout ryan-a11y-merge-to-master;
npm ci;
npm start;
```

They have been able to run the application (and also get the warnings) without a problem but I get the error above and get the following message at localhost:4200: `Cannot GET /`

**What I have tried**

- Deleted node_modules and the dist folder
- npm cache clean
- npm unlink @angular/core (both steps in the package folder and the project including it)
- npm unlink @vcd/ui-components (both steps)
- Completely removing node, npm, nmv and reinstalling them

**Workaround**

If I disable Ivy compilation, then it complains because one of the packages it uses (`@vmw/live-docs`), doesn't declare `entryComponents` for some dynamically created components (since they are not needed in Ivy compilation).

To get past that problem, I modified the code in `@vmw/live-docs` to have `entryComponents` and re-built it, copying its dist folder to node_modules in my current application. This allows me to run the app in non Ivy mode, which is not what I want

**What else can I try ?**

I am out of things to try, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because I somehow had a `~/node_modules/@vcd/ui-components` with stale references.

It seems that [node module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-nodejs-resolves-modules) was going up the tree and trying to use that version instead of the one I had configured in  `~/github/vmware-cloud-director-ui-components/tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
    "@vcd/ui-components": [
       "../../dist/components"
    ]
  }
},
```

Deleting that `node_modules` folder fixed my problem